# How can i print something to the roblox console from python?

Tags: python, memory, roblox

Im trying to print something to the roblox console from python how can i do this? heres what i tried:

```
    def Execute():
        try:
            mem = pymem.Pymem("RobloxPlayerBeta.exe")  
        except:
            subprocess.Popen("RobloxPlayerBeta.exe")
            mem = pymem.Pymem("RobloxPlayerBeta.exe")

        mem.inject_python_interpreter()  

        code = "print 'hello'"

        mem.inject_python_shellcode(code)
```

yet roblox just crashes and my console says "cannot allocate memory."

Answer (score 0):

I think you would just write print("hello"), correct me if I'm wrong.

Edit: You could also use rconsoleprint, https://synapsexdocs.github.io/custom-lua-functions/console-functions/

Answer (score -1):

Python may not be ideal for this although if you insist you can convert your .py code into .lua code